# Python Selenium Help - NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I'm already getting the data that I need (from a print test) but I think the webdriver still continues to look for elements so it returns an error. I've included my code below, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.finder.com.au/home-loans'
driver.get(url)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2080)") 

get_today = datetime.datetime.now()
today = get_today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
affiliate = 'Finder'
rank = 1

results = []

loans = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="comparison-table-0000000000"]//*')))

for i in range(1, len(loans)):
#     loan_listing = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="comparison-table-0000000000"]/tbody/tr[{i}]//a[1]'))).text
    loan_listing = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="comparison-table-0000000000"]/tbody/tr[{i}]//a[1]').text
    print(loan_listing.split(' ', 1))
```

It already prints the values I'm looking for:

[print results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii7TH.png)

But after a few secs also returns this error:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVMBv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:
This XPath `'//*[@id="comparison-table-0000000000"]//*'` is too general, it matches more than 1500 elements on that page so that `loans` list contain a lot of irrelevant elements.
After that you are printing the texts from elements matching this XPath: `//*[@id="comparison-table-0000000000"]/tbody/tr[{i}]//a[1]`. There are 20 elements per page matching this. So the first 20 results are printed correctly but your loop continues since the length of `loans` list is much longer.
So, to make your code better you can fix this line `loans = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="comparison-table-0000000000"]//*')))` to make it locate relevant elements only, as following:

```py
loans = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="comparison-table-0000000000"]/tbody/tr//a[@class="nameLink']")))
```

Or even

```py
loans = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="comparison-table-0000000000"]//a[@class="nameLink"]')))
```

Here I defined the `a` element locator to be more precisely and now this locator matches 20 relevant elements only

Comment: I'm happy I could help you, my friend!